# Multiple Select vs Single Select Statement

Tags: sql, t-sql, select

I was just wondering whats the difference between doing multiple selects vs. using a single select is there any performance gain? I saw someone did it, and I feel its like kinda out of hand such as below;

```
select @a = cBranchName from mstores where nBranchCode = 1
select @b = cBranchAddress from mstores where nBranchCode = 1
select @c = dCreateDate from mstores where nBranchCode = 1
select @d = AssignedCompanyId from mstores where nBranchCode = 1
select @e = StoreFormat from mstores where nBranchCode = 1
```

vs.

```
select @a = cBranchName 
  ,@b = cBranchAddress
  ,@c = dCreateDate
  ,@d = AssignedCompanyId
  ,@e = StoreFormat from mstores where nBranchCode = 1
```

I also presume that the 5 select's make 5 trips to the database, how can I prove that single select statement is faster than the 5 select statements,

Even though just by looking at it, I already thought that the single select statement is significantly faster than the multiple selects.

Comment: reading a book five times is faster or reading a book for a single time is faster?

Comment: @SenthilPrabhu: It's not that simple. The database optimizes your query often but i assume not in this case.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Database needs to optimizes the query which may take at-least a lil bit of seconds.

Comment: @SenthilPrabhu: The [query optimizer](http://sqlserverpedia.com/wiki/SQL_Server_Query_Optimizer_Overview) will try to optimize the query anyway when it's first executed. So that doesn't take time on consecutive calls.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Ya the code optimization takes place only once. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377729/performance-single-join-select-vs-multiple-simple-selects
If you go Deeper the Clause makes the difference while optimizing..

Answer (score 2):

Major differences:

1. Five round trips rather than one.  The speed of light/electricity takes care of this one
2. Has to examine, parse and execute 5 statements not one.  What do you think will be quicker?
3. Consistency - what happens if an update occurs between selects?
4. You can quite clearly see the work that goes on if you show the execution plan

I'm quite at a loss to understand why anyone would ever have cause to think the 5 queries would be better than one.

Answer (score 1):

I would not expect to see a significant difference between the 2 methods. After the first SELECT is executed in method #1 an execution plan will exist that the database engine can re-use for the other 4 SELECTs. And: the page might be cached at that point so a return to the disk would not be required. Method #2 is more desirable on 2 counts: it's (argueably) more elegant, and secondly it's a single command so the row will be locked whilst its being executed. In method #1 it's possible that the row will change between each SELECT

Comment: Rubbish.  Of course there's a difference.  Even if the page is cached, there's the round trips. The row will not be locked during execution but you do mention the potential to change between statements so you break even on that one.

Comment: A shared read lock will exist. I said I would not expect to see a SIGNIFICANT difference, therefore, yes, of course there's a difference

Answer (score 0):

for one table i think single select should be the number 1 choice#, and when you are dealing with multiple tables even then depending on situation  single join statement is better then multiple select statements

I think a single statement enables the database to do a lot of optimizations, as it can see all the tables it needs to scan, overhead is reduced, and it can build up the result set locally.and also a single statement will usually be easier for the next programmer to understand and to revise

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to test it to prove it though I would expect one select on a single table would be less expensive than 5. For multiple tables where a join is required, it may be less expensive to do individual selects - you'd need to use 'explain plan' to determine that ahead of time (sometimes joins can't/don't use indexes where a single table select will).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190287.aspx

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON;
GO
SELECT ProductID, StartDate, EndDate, StandardCost 
FROM Production.ProductCostHistory
WHERE StandardCost < 500.00;
GO
SET STATISTICS TIME OFF;
GO
```

Results:

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
 CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 1 ms.

 (269 row(s) affected)

SQL Server Execution Times:
 CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 2 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
 CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 1 ms.
```