# How to optimize one big scripts

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

How does sql execute the following process below; Because when I try to execute it on SSMS it takes around 15secs per item, however, when put into sql agent job, it almost take a lifetime to give an output.

```
ForProcessing is a list of items

OPEN ForProcessing
FETCH NEXT FROM ForProcessing into @HeaderID, @CompanyCode, @AssignedCompanyID, @BranchCode, @WorkDate
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    -- EOD for S1 FILE (MMS FILE)
    if exists (select 1 from mMiddlewareFiles where cType = 'O' and cVersion = @cVersion and cFile = 'S1FILE')
    BEGIN
        execute rmw_eod_S1_file @HeaderID, @AssignedCompanyID, @BranchCode, @WorkDate
    END
    -- EOD for SL FILE (CSA FILE)
    if exists (select 1 from mMiddlewareFiles where cType = 'O' and cVersion = @cVersion and cFile = 'SLFILE')
    BEGIN
        execute rmw_eod_SL_file @HeaderID, @AssignedCompanyID, @BranchCode, @WorkDate
    END
    -- EOD for C FILE (CSA FILE)
    if exists (select 1 from mMiddlewareFiles where cType = 'O' and cVersion = @cVersion and cFile = 'CFILE')
    BEGIN
        execute rmw_eod_C_file @HeaderID, @AssignedCompanyID, @BranchCode, @WorkDate
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM ForProcessing into @HeaderID, @CompanyCode, @AssignedCompanyID, @BranchCode, @WorkDate
END
```

If I am to create the function separately instead of having one big script that calls these procedures, would it significantly increase the performance?

Any advise to get into this? or how to optimize this kind of procedure?

**EDIT:**

Somewhat related to this issue of mine, inside the executed procedure I found the ff: concerns

```
DECLARE @a, @b, @c, @d, @e, etc... --the list grows 
SELECT @a = field2 from Parameters where field1 = 'UserName'
SELECT @b = field2 from Parameters where field1 = 'Name'
SELECT @c = field2 from Parameters where field1 = 'CompanyCode'
SELECT @d = field2 from Parameters where field1 = 'MachineNo'
SELECT @e = field2 from Parameters where field1 = 'Type'
```

As I have asked here [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16812672/multiple-select-vs-single-select-statement)

I wish for advise on how to optimize it, is there a better to do this such as define a table and then the fields and just query a 1 time big time select or the like..

If anyone could also give me a good alternative how to get away from fetch next or while, please do so.

Comment: You don't appear to be advancing your cursor - is that just a copy-and-paste mistake?

Comment: it was a copy mistake, i'll edit it in a while..

Comment: Depending on the number of rows in the cursor, you're looking at an awful lot of work row-by-row.  What's in the guts of the SPs you're executing?

Comment: Indeed, the row per row was awful, I once came from the like (VFP), and when I shifted to SQL I always tried to do things the way it tells me how, so when I saw this code, it was really hurting me.. inside the sp's a lot of joins happening after then would create an output file (raw) which again I think was done against SQL way of doing things, should be done by an IS instead, but then again, its the old programmer's code that I need and mostly want to improve.

Comment: You're going to have to fix the SPs and perhaps the row by row processing.  There's nothing to go on with what you've posted.  Post the SPs and maybe someone can help but until you do that don't expect too much progress, if any.

Answer (score 0):

As Rory Hunter said, you do not advance in your cursor.

call

```
FETCH NEXT FROM ForProcessing into @HeaderID, @CompanyCode, @AssignedCompanyID, @BranchCode, @WorkDate
```

again as the last statement in your loop, otherwise you get an infinite loop